# Terraform custom truststore

Tags: terraform

I have the following issue when trying to use terraform.

I try to use terraform via an enterprise proxy.

So I set the HTTPS_PROXY env variable.

But the enterprise proxy act as a "man in the middle" (parsing web pages for viruses ...) and is configured with a security server certificate issued by our enterprise own authority.

It seems that terraform is not able to connect to (https) registries because this CA Root certificate is not trusted.

Is there a way I can configure terraform to use a custom CA Root trustore with (under Windows) ?

Bellow is the error I get Terraform try to connect (at init phase)

```
<!-- language: none -->

> terraform.exe init

Initializing provider plugins...
- Checking for available provider plugins on https://releases.hashicorp.com...

Error installing provider "aws": Get https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-aws/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout.

Terraform analyses the configuration and state and automatically downloads
plugins for the providers used. However, when attempting to download this
plugin an unexpected error occured.

This may be caused if for some reason Terraform is unable to reach the
plugin repository. The repository may be unreachable if access is blocked
by a firewall.

If automatic installation is not possible or desirable in your environment,
you may alternatively manually install plugins by downloading a suitable
distribution package and placing the plugin's executable file in the
following directory:
    terraform.d/plugins/windows_amd64
```

Comment: Why is your proxy's CA cert not already in your OS trust store?

Comment: My CA cert is in the IE/Chrome truststore. But Terraform don't seems to use it.
With some tools you can set the cacert or custom truststore  via an option.

For example with Curl you can set it via this env variable :
set CURL_CA_BUNDLE=C:\tools\ROOT_CA.crt

Answer (score 0):

Finally the truststore was not in cause.

The issue was due to a setting the HTTPS_PROXY env to an httpS url rather than http.

Now it works fine with my custom root certificate in windows trust and even with NTLM authentication.